# How can I add custom fonts in Figma linux

Tags: linux, fonts

I'm designing and prototyping an android app in Figma Linux but there is no way to add custom/desktop font in the application or in the web version. Figma only lists the Google fonts only. Please help me to solve this issue. I really need to add some fonts for my native language.

Comment: Why don't you ask here https://github.com/Figma-Linux/figma-linux ? This is not a Linux distro per se.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an unofficial Figma Agent for Linux](https://github.com/neetly/figma-agent-linux).

It works perfectly on EndeavourOS to enable local font use in Figma's web app.

Despite Figma claiming to be platform-independent, the truth is that without this shim (kudos to the creator) Figma isn't viable on Linux since users are limited to a tiny selection of non-proprietary fonts.